# Disable past days in selectinputdate icefaces

Tags: java, icefaces-2

How I can disable past days in a `selectinputdate` popup in icefaces?

```
<ice:selectInputDate id="date" 
    value="#{bean.date}"
    renderAsPopup="true" required="true"
    partialSubmit = "true"   
</ice:selectInputDate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use either a `validator` or a `valueChangeListener`, as defined in the [2.0.2 TLD](http://res.icesoft.org/docs/v2_latest/compat/comps/tld/ice/selectInputDate.html)

In your case I assume you want a `valueChangeListener`. You'll have to bind a method of type void that takes a `ValueChangeEvent` as single argument, as mentioned in the previously linked docs.